# Parallel.Foreach + BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker, parallel.foreach

I am looking for feedback in case there are any known reasons I shouldn't do something like this: putting a ReportProgress within a Parallel foreach statement.  Are there any similar ways to achieve the same thing but are considered safer or better?

Code example:

```
        int iterations = 0;
        int count = items.Count;
        Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, item =>
        {
            iterations++;
            int percentComplete = (iterations/count) * 100;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
        };
```

Additional info:

I have a Windows Form program that needs to do a specific task of managing items. Utilizing multi threading has made it much faster. However it needs to report to a progress bar on the form the overall progress completed so the end user doesn't wonder if the program frozen up. The overall job can take hours in some cases. So, having a progress bar is mandatory.

Comment: Just set the [ProgressBar.Style() Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style(v=vs.110).aspx) to "Marquee".

Comment: @Idle_Mind I don't think "Marquee" will be an option for this scenario: it is important to see just how far along the work done has been completed to get an idea of time remaining.

Comment: How does your code above report any **meaningful** progress?

Comment: @Idle_Mind was pseudo code and the issue you refer to (which is now fixed via Edit) did not really impact the point of the question. but to avoid any future confusion or distractions from the actual question, has been edited...

Comment: You're still not reporting any meaningful progress.  The code is simply iterating a value that has no knowledge of the actual work being done in the BackgroundWorkers.  You could just use a standard Timer on the Form and call ReportProgress() in the Tick() event.  Why the additional threads to do this task?

Comment: I intentionally removed all code that has zero relevance to this question's topic of "BackgroundWorker within a Parallel.Foreach". I'm simply giving enough code to illustrate the question better. Don't worry about the paint color of the house when I'm only asking about the plumbing? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not wise, and possibly not even allowed to let several threads communicate with the same `BackGroundWorker`.

If you have only a limited amount of threads, like 5 in your example, consider having each thread use its own BackgroundWorker that reports its own progress.

The receiver of all progress reports should upon receipt of a report decide about the actual progress and report it to those who are interested.

```
class MyLongProgress : IDisposable
{
     public MyLongProgress()
     {
         for (int i=0; i<maxNrOfParallelProcesses; ++i)
         {
             var createdBackGroundWorker = this.CreateBackGroundWorker();
             createdBackGroundWorker.ReportProgress += this.OnProgressReport;
             backGroundWorkers.Add(createdBackGroundWorker);
         }
     }
     // TODO: implement Disposable pattern that Disposes the background workers
     private readonly List<BackGroundWorker> backGroundWorkers = new List<BackGroundWorker>();

     public void StartLongProcess()
     {
         // start your long progress, which involves starting the backGroundWorkers
         // These backGroundWorkers will report progress via OnProgressReport
     }

     private void OnProgressReport(object sender, ...)
     {
         var myBackGroundWorker = (BackGroundWorker)sender;
         // calculate the actual progress using earlier received progress reports
         MyProgressReport report = ...
         OnReportProgress(report);
     }

     public event EventHandler<MyprogressReport> ReportProgrogress;

     protected virtual void OnReportProgress(MyProgressReport report)
     {
         this.ReportProgress?.Invoke(this, report);
     }
}
```

Alternatively: create and dispose the BackGroundWorkers only during StartLongProcess. In that case you don't need IDisposable.

Comment: "...possibly not even allowed to let several threads communicate with the same BackGroundWorker." My example code does work and there are no known problems with this technique. My progress bar updates as I would expect it to. Per a coworker saying the same thing you did, is why I asked this question to get clarification. Could you elaborate on how or why your suggested approach is better?

Answer (score 1):

I think Harald is on the money with his answer. 
I've used the example shown at [this link](http://snipplr.com/view/36749/modal-progress-dialog-with-cancel-for-timeconsuming-operations-c-winforms/) in the instance of having one background worker.

You get a good feel for how it works with the following snippet (copied from the link above). I think you could maybe use that as a base to allow a collection of `DoWorkEventHandler` delegates and create a `BackgroundWorker` for each.

```
      private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // Create dialog.
         ProgressWithCancel dlgProgress = new ProgressWithCancel( "Testing progress", LongOperation);

         // Show dialog with Synchronous/blocking call.
         // LongOperation() is called by dialog.
         dlgProgress.ShowDialog(); // Synchronous/blocking call.
      }

      private void LongOperation(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
         BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

         int max = 20;
         for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
         {
            if (worker.CancellationPending) // See if cacel button was pressed.
            {
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Similate time for clean-up.
               break;
            }

            int percent = i * 100 / max;

            string userState = percent.ToString(); // render a string to display on the progress dialog.

            // Append to string just to show multi-line user-status info.
            if (percent >= 45 && percent <= 55) { userState += "Half way"; }
            if (percent >= 85) { userState += "Almost done"; }

            worker.ReportProgress(percent, userState); // Report percent and user-status info to dialog.

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800); // Simulate time-consuming operation
         }
      }


// Implementation (in ProgressWithCancel.cs)

namespace ProgressWithCancel
{
   public partial class ProgressWithCancel : Form
   {
      public ProgressWithCancel(string whyWeAreWaiting, DoWorkEventHandler work)
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Text = whyWeAreWaiting; // Show in title bar
         backgroundWorker1.DoWork += work; // Event handler to be called in context of new thread.
      }

      private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         label1.Text = "Cancel pending";
         backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); // Tell worker to abort.
         btnCancel.Enabled = false;
      }

      private void Progress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
      }

      private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
         label1.Text = e.UserState as string;
      }

      private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
         Close();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this utilizes any sort of multi threading to run several tasks at the same time, which is an important part of my question

Comment: That example doesn't. It just uses the one. I was just posting it as an example, and stated you could use it as a starting point, but update it to work with multiple BackgroundWorkers.